# Is there any issue with LAN-card in ubuntu?

Tags: drivers

Will Ubuntu 14.04 will work if desktop is already fitted with LAN card?

Comment: Generally, the support for LAN cards is extremly good. But you don't need to guess. Simply create a Ubuntu Live-USB stick and test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short Answer: Yes**

However, there may be incompatibilities. The worst that can happen is that the LAN card doesn't work due to driver incompatibilities. And, this is rather rare and is almost always correctable. You are most likely safe.

To test it, boot a Live Ubuntu session. If it works there, it will work on an install.

Comment: To test it yourself, you can always boot a Ubuntu 14.04 in live seesion and see if the LAN card works. If it works there, it will work on an install.